# Android - How to pick numbers from a generated list?

Tags: java, android, random, collections

This question is based on my other question, make sure to take a look at it:
[Android - Generate non-repetitive random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319069/android-generate-non-repetitive-random-numbers/33319181#33319181)

I have a collection that shuffles, but how can I pick the numbers one by one after "next" button is pressed?

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
```

This code is executed when the app is opened.

```
qid =
```

This code is executed after "Next" button is pressed.

I'm confused on what the question id(qid) should be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pick a random index between 0 and the size of the list, then do list.get(index)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a counter. Call your method.

```
static int counter = 0;

public static int getNextQuestion(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
 if(counter == list.size() + 1) return -1;
 return list.get(counter++);
}
```